# Convert axes coordinates to pixel coordinates

Tags: c++, c, math

I'm looking for an efficient way to convert axes coordinates to pixel coordinates for multiple screen resolutions.

For example if had a data set of values for temperature over time, something like:

```
int temps[] = {-8, -5, -4, 0, 1, 0, 3};
int times[] = {0, 12, 16, 30, 42, 50, 57};
```

What's the most efficient way to transform the dataset to pixel coordinates so I could draw a graph on a 800x600 screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're going from `TEMP_MIN` to `TEMP_MAX`, just do:

```
y[i] = (int)((float)(temps[i] - TEMP_MIN) * ((float)Y_MAX / (float)(TEMP_MAX - TEMP_MIN)));
```

where `#define Y_MAX (600)`.  Similarly for the x-coordinate.  This isn't tested, so you may need to modify it slightly to deal with the edge-case (`temps[i] == TEMP_MAX`) properly.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to determine the maximum and minimum values along each axis.  Then you can do:

```
x_coord[i] = (x_val[i] - x_max) * X_RES / (x_max - x_min);
```

...and the same for Y.  (Although you will probably want to invert the Y axis).

Comment: You'll probably need to do this in floating-point to achieve the correct accuracy (as in my answer), and to avoid overflow issues.

Comment: @Oli: Yep, that can be achieved by making `X_RES` a floating point constant like `800.0`.